# How to best structure a large web application over multiple servers

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, forge

What would be the best server setup for the following, I am planning to use digital ocean with forge. I am starting with digital oean and picking my droplets, (As you can realise I have not done this before so any help will be valuable).

The application works like so , I have a website where users can log in and a website where managers can log in. On the users website the user will be able to do things concerning his or her own profile ex..

On the managers website the users will be able to do things concerning all the users of the users website,

Now thinking in terms of server I have come up with the following idea. I need a vps droplet for my websites all of them a droplet for my dataserver , then here is the question.

A user on the users website and on the managrs website both of them are users, but they depending on the application and privlages they can only do certain things, In my projects right now I have two different applications each with theyr own models and controllers, but If I change this to a sever based vps setup . I am hoping to have the following setup...

an application server that runs the things that are the same for a user or his roles no matter on which application he or she is, an application server for the specific users on users website or managers website,

is this possible , or am I barking up the wrong tree, I am still ignorant in the usages of differnet servers and what would be best practices, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually comes down to your requirements and priorities.

If you need managers website to be accessible all the time no matter what happens with users website, then sure, you can put it at the separate server. If on the other hand there is no such need, I'd suggest to put both websites at the same server, with separate database server. There are probably much fewer managers than users, therefore managers website will consume very little resources. But you also could buy cheaper droplet for managers and more expensive one for users. As you can see, there are countless possibilities.

Additional resources:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-common-server-setups-for-your-web-application